# How to use mysql database as dataset for machine learning

Tags: python, mysql, machine-learning, neural-network, bigdata

i have done a project using django with mysql database to collect sales data
i want to make some prediction from the data like demand forecast using ANN/SVM

is it possible to take mysql database as input directly or should i convert them to csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your server/machine has enough RAM you can read data directly from MySQL into Pandas DataFrame and then feed that DataFrame to sklearn/Keras/Tensorflow.

Demo:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)

df = pd.read_sql("select * from tab_name", conn)
```